# Cant see new record line in Access 2010 form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form where people can enter phone bills for that particular month. I have 6 fields and the form is not linked to any table or query. I allow users to choose the name in the name field which is linked to 'staff table' from where i get all the names.
The problem I am having as of now is that I don't see a new record line after i completely enter all the data. I also have the form cycle properties set as "All Records".
Please help

Answer (score 2):

You said that your form was not "linked" (bound) to any table or query so the "New Record" (`*`) line does not apply; your form is just a single-page collection of unbound controls (combo boxes, text boxes, etc.).

If you want a "New Record" line then you'll need to bind the form to a table or query.

If you don't want to bind the form then you have to:

- create a button on your form to save the current control (field) values to a new record in your table via VBA code,
- clear (some?) of the previous control values so they are ready to accept new values, and then
- allow the user to repeat the process to add another record.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't bound to a table, there's nowhere for a 'new' record to go.  You should create a 'New Record' or 'Clear' button to blank out the form for new entry.